# What is the concept of symbol perpendicular to power and integral interval?

Tags: polynomials, notation, random, integral-geometry

I saw the 
$ E_n = \frac{1}{\pi} $$\int_{\bot \infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-{\frac{(n+1)^2 t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}} dt$$ $ and $ a.v(t)= C^{\bot1/2}a.C^{1/2}v(t)$ and Similar formula
 in the '[How many zeros of a random polynomial are real?](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9501224)' article. I wonder what is this? why ${\bot} $ in the integral interval or in the power? I don't understand its meaning. Could you please explain or link to that What is the concept of symbol perpendicular to power and integral interval?

Comment: In this article, it looks like the symbol "$\perp$" is used in place of "$-$" in several places. I would guess these are typesetting errors.

Comment: @MPW I don't think so. The 'perpendicular'  word has been used several times in the text.. I understand the text, but not the formulas.. Maybe I didn't even understand the text correctly, but I'm sure it's the symbol perpendicular to the formulas.

Comment: In some places it is used correctly, but in others it doesn't make sense and I would expect a minus sign instead. For example, what is the real number $4e^{\perp 2x}$ in the numerator of the fraction in Theorem 2.2? I suspect it should be $4e^{-2x}$.

Comment: @MPW You're right. thank you very much